# Show top {n} words by occurrence and include count

Tags: c#, string, sorting, split, unique

Making an application where a sub function is to show the most commonly used, unique words in a discussion board (non useful words like "the, "and" etc are already filtered out)

They've requested a list of the top 10 words used, and the percentage they occur. I can take care of percentage, but I'm not sure the most efficient way to take a single string of say 10,000 words, and show the top 10 occurrences, and the number of times each of the top 10 occurs.

Comment: Start reading up on [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx).

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://scottchamberlin.tumblr.com/post/55152416452/linqinterview), pretty much what you're look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`LINQ`'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method:

```
var listOfWords = GetMyListOfTenThousandWords();

listOfWords.GroupBy(
    low => low, 
    // Return an anonymous object with the word and it's count
    (key, result) => new { Word = key, Count = result.Count() } 
).OrderByDescending(w => w.Count)
.Take(10);
```

I have a quick writeup about 2 of the overloads of `GroupBy` [here](http://davidzych.com/2013/06/08/linq-groupby-explanations-and-examples/) if you'd like to learn more.

Comment: Add "OrderByDescending(p=>p.Count).Take(10)" at end of your expression

Comment: @Dave Does this assume that 'listOfWords' is a List<string>?

Comment: @Dave This seems to have broken the string down into individual chars. I'm going to try loading into a List<string> first and see if that helps.

Comment: @Wesley it assumes it's an `IEnumerable<string>` which includes a `List<string>`. What do you mean it broke the strings down to chars? This shouldn't do that...

Comment: @DaveZych if the input is a single string of 10,000 words, it returns to me a list of each chars occurance

Comment: @Wesley - That's because a `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. This solution works on every `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Wesley Right, that makes sense. Since `string` implements `IEnumerable` it allows you to use the `LINQ` methods. The `listOfWords` variable in the example assumes it's a `IEnumerable<string>`, where each item is one whole word.

Comment: @DaveZych Perfect, works great, although you should remove 'return' and just leave 'new'. Otherwise it throws an exception :)